# How to make a variable accessible by all Swift files?

Tags: ios, swift, variables, xcode6, global-variables

Say I were to assign a variable in the app delegate. How could I access this variable in all my other view controllers/swift files without using segues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate` gives access to the singleton application object, so:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let x = appDelegate.myVariable
```

Comment: So I would just calling this over and over again to access the variable?

Comment: Create that `appDelegate` as an instance variable in your viewController and you can access it in all methods of your viewController.

Comment: So now, what if I created the variable in a regular view controller. The above way wouldn't work right?

Comment: any ideas on what to do?